# Execute looping bash script via PHP without interrupting server function

Tags: php, bash, apache

I have an apache server with a login page where I want to pass the credentials provided at the login to authenticate an upload of a file sent to the server. I'm very new to this

When I upload a file to the server, it responds with a 500 code. I think the problem is with autoupload.sh because when I comment out line 3 of upload.php, the error code ceases and the uploads to the server work, but naturally now the files are never uploaded to the external service.

The point of autoupload.sh is watch for monitor for added files to the `/uploads/` directory, upload them to a webservice, then delete them locally on completion, and then exit.

`index.php` is a form that looks like

```
<form action="uploadpage.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text"/>
<input name="field2" type="password"/>
<a href='/tmp/data.txt></a>
//html content
//more html content
```

`uploadpage.php` contains another form:

```
`<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
//more html and css`
```

`upload.php` looks like:

```
`$old_path=getcwd(); //preserve working directory
chdir('/path/to/dir/');
shell_exec("./autoupload.sh $_POST['field1'] $_POST['field2']");
chrdir($old_path);
//other stuff`
```

and finally `autoupload.sh` looks like:

```
user=$1
pw=$2
while IFS= read -r file; do
curl -u $user:$pw -T "/path/to/$file" https://web@site.com && rm -f "path/to/$file"
exit 1
done < <(inotifywait -m q -r -e MOVED_TO --format '%f' /var/www/html/uploads/)
```

Comment: Scheduled tasks/cronjobs are your friend here as as far as I know.  Php does not support multi-threading

Comment: Your PHP code wouldn't execute until the upload has completes anyways. You cannot have PHP simultaneously stream the uploaded file to some other location as it's uploading to PHP in the first place. Plus, you are wide open to shell injection attacks. consider what happens if someone posts  `field1=; rm -rf /`. Boom goes your server.

Comment: Well I don't want `autoupload.sh` to run every fixed interval of time. Is it not possible to execute the bash script in the background with `shell_exec()` and have the remainder of `upload.php` continue to execute? I understand that `shell_exec` is probably mainly used for simple bash commands, not ones that will only terminate on a certain condition.

Comment: @Marc B, thanks for pointing that out, I'll sanitize the inputs. I am not trying to simultaneously steam uploaded files. Inotifywait doesn't trigger until the upload to the server has completed. Pretty sure of that because this implementation was working before I added the 'login'